# KeePass on OpenBSD and libpng error

Tags: openbsd

I am trying to run KeePass on OpenBSD. I installed Mono from packages and downloaded KeePass-2.30-portable. Unforunately I can't start KeePass because of this errors:

```
SendMessage (27263013, 0x112c, 0x4, 0x4)
libpng error: invalid after png_start_read_image or png_read_update_info
libpng error: invalid after png_start_read_image or png_read_update_info
libpng error: invalid after png_start_read_image or png_read_update_info
libpng error: invalid after png_start_read_image or png_read_update_info
SendMessage (27263007, 0x101f, 0x0, 0x0)
SendMessage (0, 0x1203, 0x0, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
SendMessage (0, 0x1204, 0x0, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
SendMessage (0, 0x1203, 0x1, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
SendMessage (0, 0x1204, 0x1, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
SendMessage (0, 0x1203, 0x2, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
SendMessage (0, 0x1204, 0x2, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
SendMessage (0, 0x1203, 0x3, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
SendMessage (0, 0x1204, 0x3, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
SendMessage (0, 0x1203, 0x4, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
SendMessage (0, 0x1204, 0x4, 0x7f7ffffd1650)
* Assertion at strenc.c:183, condition `utf8!=NULL' not met

Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) KeePass.Native.NativeMethods.GetFileAttributes (string) <0xffffffff>
  at KeePass.Native.NativeMethods.FileExists (string) <0x0002d>
  at KeePass.Util.WinUtil.RemoveZoneIdentifier (string) <0x0006e>
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.OnFormLoadParallelAsync (object) <0x00090>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Abort trap (core dumped)
```

I would appreciate any help.